# Force SSL only on certain pages with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https

I have found a solution for setting one page on my WordPress site to use https though I am trying to apply the ssl to two pages instead of one. I have tried various if or statements, but can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Below is my if statement that works perfectly on one page:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
   { 
   if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/bill-pay/')
       {
         header("Location:http://example.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}", 301);
         exit;
       }
   elseif ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/bill-pay/') 
       {
         header("Location: https://example.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}", 301);
         exit;
       }
   }
```

For the sake of clarity, I have only added my version that works for one page.

Comment: Don't do that. SSL is great. SSL is (now) cheap. SSL protects your users. SSL improves your SEO ([yes, really](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html)). Just turn on SSL for every page. Have a plain HTTP site just to redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: @Quentin: Well since HTTPS effectively disables long-term caching in most browsers, that’s a bit idiotic of Google IMHO – especially since on the other hand with their PageSpeed stuff they want people to use caching of resources as much as possible …

Comment: @CBroe Not if you do your caching headers correctly. `Cache-Control: public`

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I agree with @CBroe, the caching factors are more valuable than applying SSL across the site.

Comment: @Byron The caching factors are only an issue if you do it wrong.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Thank you,  I wasn’t aware of that. Makes total sense though. That largely nullifies any concerns in that regard of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would have thought a straight-forward...

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{ 
   if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' && !($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/bill-pay/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/other-page/'))
   {
     header("Location:http://example.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}", 301);
     exit;
   }
   elseif ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on' && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/bill-pay/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/other-page/')) 
   {
     header("Location: https://example.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}", 301);
     exit;
   }
}
```

... should do the trick

**Edit**

This code might be more appropriate, given the comments:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/bill-pay/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/other-page/'))
{
   if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) 
   {
      header("Location: https://example.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}", 301);
      exit;
   }
} 
else 
{
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) 
   {
      header("Location: http://example.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}", 301);
      exit;
   }
}
```

Remember `empty()` resolves to `false` if the value is not set ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I thought this solution would work as well, though with this approach I receive a redirect loop error on both pages. All other pages on the site load correctly. 

Any ideas on what would cause this error?

I wish I could provide you the working example but the site is live with an active email campaign so I cannot take these pages down for the time being.

Comment: Hmm... Just wondering why you check the value `on`? http://php.net states "Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol. ". I can see a redirect loop there if `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` was a non-empty value other than `on`

Comment: Also remember to clear your browser cache before testing - 301 redirects have a habit of sticking around...

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that only securing part of the site effectively means almost no security at all. Via MITM or other vulnerabilities an attacker can easily rewrite the links to the secure pages to outside pages under control of the attacker.

Remember, SSL is not only about a secure connection but also about proving who you (=your site) really are. Please, do secure your whole site, run it through [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html), follow its recommendations. It's better for everyone, especially your customers.